# Extract not numeric values from a file

Tags: unix

I'm attempting to extract not numeric values from a matrix like this:

```
32540_at        0.138306  78047_s_at    0.133885 81737_at   0.163546 81811_at   0.181725 AAGAB          0.157073 AARSD1         0.114351
```

(the file contains rows of different length but each time the name is followed by a number)

Specifically, the output I need is the following:

```
32540_at 78047_s_at 81737_at 81811_at AAGAB AARSD1
```

Since it is too difficult to me (due to my inexperience in Unix programming) to extract the alpha numeric characters due to the structure of names like 81737_at I'm attempting to extract differentially the not numeric characters from the numeric ones.
That is, removing the numeric ones, the not numeric fields will stay there directly.
How this can be done?

Best,

Eleonora

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With sensible `RS` and `ORS` settings, this is fairly straight forward with `awk`:

```
awk -v RS=' +|\n' -v ORS=' ' '!/^[0-9.]+$/'
```

Output:

```
32540_at 78047_s_at 81737_at 81811_at AAGAB AARSD1
```

#### Explanation

- `RS=' +|\n'`: Separate each record with whitespace or newline.
- `ORS=' '`: Inserts a space after each record printed.
- `!/^[0-9.]+$/`: If record doesn't only contain numbers and a dots, print it. A more correct number pattern would be (no considering scientific notation): `!/^([0-9]+\.[0-9]*|[0-9]*\.[0-9]+|[0-9]+\.?)$`.

Comment: Hi Thor! Thanks a lot for your help! since I have a list of files called for ex. split1.txt, split2.txt how is possible to insert your code in a loop taking in input all the files that start with split? Thanks again

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with the output. If it can be sequential, just add the filenames after the `awk` command, `awk` will parse them automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You say name is always followed by number? How about:

```
tr -s ' ' '\n' your_file | sed -n '1~2p'
```

Comment: Yes exactly! The name is the gene name whereas the number is a value of mutual information. I need only the gene name